# Подсчет слов из одного символа

Tags: python

Дана строка s из комбинации латинских строчных букв, разделенных пробелами. Напишите функцию unit(s), которая возвращает количество слов в этой строке, которые содержат только один символ. Типа, использую метод s.split, а дальше не понимаю как делать.

Comment: `s.split` - хорошее начало. Сможете написать цикл, который считает короткие слова с его применением?

Comment: Ваши попытки решения должны быть отражены в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно задаче, мы должны пройтись по каждому слову из строки и если оно состоит из одного символа - прибавить к результату +1, в обратном случае - ничего не делать. После того как пройдемся по всем словам - вывести результат.

К примеру есть такая строка

```
s = "I am new to Python"
```

Объявляем функцию

```
def unit(s)
```

Далее мы можем использовать метод `split`, как вы и указали, для того чтобы сделать список из отдельных слов из строки, и в качестве аргумента использовать "пробел" -

```
word_list = s.split(" ")
```

Можем сразу создать переменную с результатом, где будем вести счет слов.

```
result = 0
```

Далее нужно сделать цикл, где мы будем пробегаться ко каждому елементу списка.
сделать мы это можем сделать следующим образом:

```
for word in word_list:
```

Где `word` это элемент списка `word_list`
Далее нужно составить условие проверки. Это мы можем сделать с помощью условия `if`.
Что бы определить из скольких символов состоит слово, мы можем воспользоваться методом `len`, где аргументов будет `word`. И само условие где количество символов в слове == 1. Если условие выполняется - прибавить 1 к результату, иначе - ничего не делать. После цикла вывести результат переменной `result`

```
if len(word) == 1:
   result += 1
print(result)
```

На основе мною выше написано, можете попробовать собрать все в кучу и выполнить код.
Дайте знать если помог